# How to account for exponential oversampling?

Tags: normalization, weighted-data

I have a dataset of frequencies from 20Hz to 20kHz. The measurement rig that created the dataset doesn't sample evenly across this frequency range. There is a much higher density of sampling happening in the low frequencies compared to the high ones. In fact, you can perfectly represent the `n-th` frequency being sampled using the equation `f(n) = 20 * 1.01**n`

I am analyzing these frequencies and I need to account for this oversampling of low frequencies, using a weighting function. Samples which occur densely should be weighed less heavily, and samples that happen in the higher frequencies and are more sparse should be weighed more heavily.

Is there a mathematical way to normalize for this behavior? A rather crude way, for example, would be to take the number of frequencies from 1-500, 500-1000, 1000-1500, etc. and divide the result of each frequency measurement by the # of samples in its region. However, since I know the exact formula used by the measurement rig, it feels like there is a more mathematical solution for this.

Comment: Are you trying to model some sort of this behavior. If so can you please explain what that is and what you're trying to predict. That would be helpful.